# Number of digits common between two numbers(Unique digits)

Tags: python

```
def number(m,n):
    count=0
    str1=str(m)
    str2=str(n)
    for i in str1:
        if i in str2:
            count+=1
    print count
```

I am trying to find the number of times a digit repeats between two numbers.

What happens when I call `number(242,321)` is:

`count` value gets equal to `2` instead of `1` which would be the desired output; only 2 gets repeated..

Comment: you have to be a bit more specific with your requirements. Does the position matter for example?

Comment: @JonClements you may want to reread that. He only has one loop and the `i` is perfectly fine as a variable here. The problem is only that he doesn't ignore duplicate digits.

Comment: @Zinki oops... my sleepy eyes conjured up a for there... my bad - thanks.

Comment: @sam007 The problem with your code is that you do not account for duplicates in the two numbers.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without using .intersection method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a deduped version of your digits. Prolly use sets and take their intersection:

```
def number(m,n):
    return len(set(str(m)).intersection(str(n)))
```

---

```
>>> number(242, 321)
1
```

Comment: beat me for like 10 secs. I got to buy a mechanical keyboard. xD